# What is the language below and where can I learn it?

Tags: shellcode

As I am subscribed to the Exploit-DB Twitter feed, I see many exploits with code looking like this:

`\x3c\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x3e\x0d\x0a\x3c\x6d\x65\x74\x61\x20\x68\x74\x74\x70\x2d\x65\x71\x75\x69\x76`

I know this is used as a buffer overflow attack but, how and where do I learn to code/make  it?

Comment: It looks like you are asking the very broad question: how do I make exploits?

Answer (score 2):

That's just ascii values of characters. Use a language that understands `\x00` characters:

```
$ perl -E 'say "\x3c\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x3e\x0d\x0a\x3c\x6d\x65\x74\x61\x20\x68\x74\x74\x70\x2d\x65\x71\x75\x69\x76"'
<html>
<meta http-equiv
```

To construct your own:

```
$ perl -E '
    $secret = "hello world"; 
    say join "", map {sprintf "\\\x%x", ord} split "", $secret;
'
\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64
```

Comment: Where can I learn how to code/create these ASCII values of characters in the form of exploitation?

Comment: @MattLubbers http://defindit.com/ascii.html